# IndexOf indicates that an object doesn't exist, even though it should

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, angular-material

I'm trying to get the index of an item in a database query, but for some reason I'm getting **-1** when trying to use `indexOf` on the data.

The data is displayed in a `md-select` that repeats over a collection of objects (roles):

```
<div layout="row">
    <md-input-container>
        <label>Job Activity:</label>
        <md-select ng-model="activity" required>
            <md-option ng-repeat="activity in activities" ng-value="activity">
                {{ activity.Description }}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Displaying works absolutely fine, but when I submit the form that the above `md-select` lives in, I simply cannot find the index of the selected activity in the collection of activities / roles, even though it **COMES** from that collection and no manipulation occurs.

Here is the submit that occurs when the form has been submitted. Role is the `role` that has been selected from the `md-select`:

```
vm.submitEmployment = function (role) {  
    console.log(role);
    console.log($scope.activities.indexOf($scope.role));
    console.log($scope.activities);

    $scope.data.role = role.Id;
    $scope.data.roleIndex = $scope.activities.indexOf($scope.role);
    $window.location.href = '#!/additionalInformation';
}
```

The above `console.logs` give me this:

[image]

Now I'm not rocket scientist, but those two objects look exactly the same for me. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I cant see you setting $scope.role = role. Try $scope.data.roleIndex = $scope.activities.indexOf(role);

Comment: You can't compare objects directly, as they may have additonal metadata like `$$hashkey` etc. Try comparing with properties in it like `id` or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter your method slightly, using the [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=example) method to get what you want. The lodash _.findIndex() achieves the same thing, if you use lodash:

```
vm.submitEmployment = function (role) {

  // the idx variable should hold your index number
  var idx = $scope.activities.findIndex((item) => $scope.role.Id === item.Id);

}
```

Comment: Note that `findIndex()` has limited browser support

Answer (score 1):

try to map your array to get IDs then search the index of your Id :

```
$scope.activities.map(function(role) { 
   return role.Id;
}).indexOf(role.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

> indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict
>   equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator)

```
var a = {a: 2}
var b = {a: 2}
a === b // false
```

> The reason for this is that internally JavaScript actually has two different approaches for testing equality. Primitives like strings and numbers are compared by their value, while objects like arrays, dates, and plain objects are compared by their reference. That comparison by reference basically checks to see if the objects given refer to the same location in memory.

So, if you are searching by `id` try something like:

```
$scope.activities.map(function(a) { return a.id; }).indexOf($scope.role.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with using ES6, you can use the findIndex function. So, you can do something like this:

```
const index = $scope.activities.findIndex(item => item.id === role.id);
```